# Does Sqlite DATETIME Type store timezone information?

Tags: .net, sqlite, datetime, fluent-nhibernate

I am currently using Fluent-NHibernate with .NET to manage my database objects. When I debug my code in C# the datetime contains a timezone. The datetime string looks like the following:

Calling date.ToString("O") yields the string "2016-05-30T17:33:00.0000000Z"

When I look in the sqlite database the timezone information seems to be missing. Also when I receive the object from the database and debug, I get the following string:

Calling date date.ToString("O") yields the string "2016-05-30T17:33:00.0000000"

Any clarification regarding sqlite datetime types would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not have a DATETIME type.

Dates and types can be stored [in several types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), but the formats understood by the built-in date/time functions do not have a time zone.

Comment: If you run a SQLite database using .NET, [DateTime.Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_Ticks) is used nowadays. You can then read them out as follows: `DateTime.FromBinary(dataReader.GetInt64(ordinal))`